# How to query and sort nested array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So first things first, here is the data model

[image: data model sample]

All i want is do a find where the result is a list of `applications` sorted by date and limited by 5 elements

Comment: So, what have you tried to achieve, that what you want? Because we can't help, if you don't show us your code.

Comment: I don't have what code to show because I don't know how to solve this issue. It is stated clearly what I want to achieve: Query a list of `applications` sorted by date and limited by 5 elements. `applications` is a nested array inside my schema, and I want to display the newest ones, regardless of the object they're in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection will give only the desired fields of a document, in this case, if you want only the `applications` list with the `_id` field you could mention that in `$project` as shown below in the query, and the result is sorted by `appliedDate` field `descending` order (most recent ones comes first) and limited 5 records.

Assuming your collection name is `test` you could fire the below query to achieve the desired results:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$applications"}, 
  {$sort: {"applications.appliedDate": -1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", applications: {$push:"$applications"}}},
  {$limit: 5},
  {"$project": {"applications": 1}}
]);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. thank you so much. Though, should I be concerned with this taking too long to run if I run this inside a GET method in my API?